# How to turn IPL function into EPL function in c++

Tags: c++

I am trying to make a code on binary trees, I have figured out how to find the Internal Path Length for my Binary tree but I am having trouble figuring out how to change my function to find EPL. I think they are pretty similar so it should be pretty similar to IPL right? Below is my IPL function, any help would be appreciated!

```
int IPL(BNode* current, int &count)
{
if(current == NULL) 
{
    count = 0;
    return 0;
}
else if(current->getLeft() == NULL && current->getRight() == NULL)
{
    count = 1;
    return 0;
}
else 
{
    count = 1;
    int leftCount;
    int rightCount;
    int sum = IPL(current->getLeft(), leftCount) + IPL(current->getRight(), rightCount);

    count += leftCount + rightCount;

    return(sum + count - 1);
}
}
```

Comment: You are messing with uninitialized variables and it is hard to tell if you should actually be taking the 'count' parameter as a reference.

Comment: I'm taking count so that it can be used again when it goes through the function again when declaring sum. Should I make it a global instead?

Comment: What do you think EPL means?

Comment: External Path Length

Comment: I found a few references to External Path Length ... but they lead to something called an 'external node'?